# How validation in next line for datetimepicker?

Tags: kendo-ui

In my project I have two datepicker both are validate with validation message but message is overlapping on datetimepcker how to show message in next line.

My code:
 http://jsbin.com/ufimom/116/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the following CSS style:

```
span.k-tooltip
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 24px;
    left: -1px;
}
```

See it running here: http://jsbin.com/ufimom/132/edit

Comment: hi onabai  here i am geeting error  that "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'validate' of undefined" after enter the value in datepicker can you  check it once please

Comment: Check the `id` of the different elements in your code as well as if they refer to an HTML element, Kendo UI object,...

Comment: Which is the url of the code that you are looking at? In http://jsbin.com/ufimom/132/edit when you introduce a date in the first input and click on submit you get an error in console because you are using a variable that is not defined yet...

Answer (score 0):

Ideally Kendo Validator places its tooltips besides the validated input. However, if the input is later enhanced to a ComboBox, AutoComplete or other Kendo Widget, placing the tooltip beside the input may cover important information or break the widget rendering. In this case, you can specify exactly where you want the tooltip to be placed by adding a span with data-for attribute set to the validated input name and a class .k-invalid-msg.

```
<div id="myform">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
    <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="name"></span>
 </div>
```

[Kendo Customizing the tooltip position](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/validator/overview#customizing-the-tooltip-position)